# How to set textView in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a problem with `TextView`. I have a layout, where there are two layouts (one is 10% and the other 90% of the area), `TextView` is placed in the first layout. The problem is that the text is to be shown at the center and at the 2 lines of text layout begins to grow, the same is reduced even though the layout below that is a place on the second line of text. My goal is to set the `TextView` text was occupying its entire surface but in the 1/2/3 lines to the size of the layout remained the same all the time.

[Screen how it should look like](http://i58.tinypic.com/15fof28.jpg)

EDIT:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="asasd asd asd asd asd s" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" 
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please show Your xml layout file

Comment: You should set fixed height to the parent Layout of the `TextView`. You can use dimen folder to set dimentions

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#000fff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#2f01dd">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```